# Compiling a C-project under RaspBian getting undefined reference to `powf'

Tags: c, hyperlink, raspbian

The make-file look like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

# Define the source files
SRC = wh1080_rf.c bcm2835.c bmp085.c parameters.c

# Define the object files by replacing each SRC .c with .o
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

# Define the final executable name
EXE = wh1080_rf

all: $(EXE)
     @echo Compilation successful

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -lm $(OBJ) -o $(EXE)

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

The project is an old one contained in a GIT-repository: https://github.com/Kevin-Sangeelee/wh1080_rf

I cloned it and used it as it is. I tried to add the link directive '-lm' but no success.
Would be nice to get some help here.

The error message:

```
 make all
gcc -lm -c -Wall -o wh1080_rf.o wh1080_rf.c
gcc -lm -c -Wall -o bcm2835.o bcm2835.c
gcc -c -Wall   -c -o bmp085.o bmp085.c
gcc -lm -c -Wall -o parameters.o parameters.c
gcc -lm wh1080_rf.o bcm2835.o bmp085.o parameters.o -o wh1080_rf
/usr/bin/ld: bmp085.o: in function `read_bmp085':
bmp085.c:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `powf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: wh1080_rf] Error 1
```

Comment: Try with ```-lm``` at the end of the linker command

Comment: Please show the error message(s) as text verbatim.

Comment: `CFLAGS=-c -Wall -lm`

Comment: Teriffic!  I changed the line to: $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE) -lm  ** And it works!** Solved in a few minutes!

Comment: Yes! I'm not used with gcc dont know much about "make" so your advice was needed.

Comment: Libraries like `-lm` should normally be listed after the object files on the command line.  They usually belong in the `make` macro LDLIBS; if they are in unusual locations (`-lm` won't be in an unusual location), you'd add `-L/library/location` to LDFLAGS.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you mean "$(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE) -lm"? I should better used what gulpr wrote "CFLAGS=-c -Wall -lm" ? I made my correction before I saw gulpr:s second comment.

Comment: @larand: Yes, that (`$(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE) -lm`) would be better than alternatives.  However, I'd recommend using something more like `$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)` — that is more nearly a standard rule.  The `$@` is a shorthand for the program being built; the $(CFLAGS) provides compiler flags to the linking phase too (in particular, if you have `-g` in CFLAGS, it means your executable is linked with debugging too), and the LDFLAGS contains things such as `-L/path/to/library` options and LDLIBS contains things such as `-lm`.    Having to supply `$(OBJ)` is a nuisance.